# Exchange 2010 distribution group change the sender email address

Tags: exchange-2010, distribution-lists

I have a `distribution group` that contains internal and external members.
the requirement is when a member of the `DL` reply, forward or send an email to this specific `DL` , the sender email should be the email address associated with the `DG` and not the email of the sender.
Is there a way to achieve that with `Exch10`?
If not is there a different way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Address rewriting on Edge Transport servers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996806(v=exchg.150).aspx)

You can use a transport rule to define this. Just rewrite the header / body of emails FROM sender sent TO the DG as the DG's email.
There are several examples in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think that's exactly what i am looking for , but i am still confused about the command . so what i want is to to change the email address of incoming emails to the address email1@domain.com to look like they are coming from email1@doamin.com   . How to achive that

Comment: It's all in the article. Basically you have to rewrite the field MAIL FROM in the envelope and whatever field you want to change in the header (From, Sender, Reply-To or whatever). I won't give you a step-by-step tutorial how to achieve that. (And don't forget about the possible confusion you could create...)

Comment: Thanks so much for your support, I voted up your answer and i will accept it as an answer.
Last question: I dont have the edge Role on my exchange , it's just Hub . so i cant run those commands right?

Comment: I assume you only use Exchange for internal messages? Or maybe only for the databases or whatever, doesn't really matter:
If you don't have the edge role in Exchange you can't rewrite anything out-of-the-box. There are some workarounds for that, "ugly" workarounds though (writing a DLL for example).